# %d in scanf not working. number 4223092 comes up

Tags: c, printf, scanf

Can anyone help me with this code? I don't see any problem, but somehow it doesn't work. When I typed my favorite number and press enter, the number 4223092 came up.

---

```
int target;
int after;

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    printf("What is 6 x 4?: ");
    scanf("%d", &target);

    if (target == 24) {
        printf("Correct!\n");
        printf("By the way what is your favorite number?: ");
        scanf("%d", &after);
        printf("%d is my favorite number too!\n", &after);

    } else {
        printf("Wrong!\n");
        printf("By the way what is your favorite number?: ");
        scanf("%d", &after);
        printf("%d is my favorite number too!\n", &after);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is teh code you have? the order is, _weird_...

Comment: That's not your actual code. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: remove `&` from *`printf`* - a `&` for a `printf` argument isn't ever right (unless the corresponding specifier happens to be `%p` and then you'd require a cast to void anyway). Your compiler should have produced a warning.

Answer (score 4):

In your code

```
 printf("%d is my favorite number too!\n", &after);
```

you don't need the `&`. You want to print the value, not the address.

Just to let you know, in it's current form, passing a `int *` as argument to `%d` invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So, you cannot justify the output in any ways.

`%d` expects an argument of type `int`, not `int *`. Passing an incompatible type of argument invokes the UB.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, P9

> [...] If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Comment: @ScottHunter That's already there in the answer, is not it? BTW, it's UB, so you cannot rely on the output.

Comment: It wasn't when I wrote it.

Comment: I am glad that you have linked the calm, moderate Wikipedia page for UB, rather than the panicked nonsense that too often appears regarding UB here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @thb I read the *first* paragraph of the wikipedia page and it is total garbage.

Comment: Hm, both the answers are downvoted. Reason?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala What about ["In computer programming..."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) is garbage?

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because the question is a typo and you should have flagged it for closure instead of answering it. It does not help any future readers in its current state.

Comment: @chux As for the "In computer programming", it talks about some behaviour that happens on runtime, when the ISO 9899 says that it is "behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements", period.

Answer (score 1):

The printf function does not require the address of a variable to print to stdout. Just pass the name of the variable like so:

```
printf("%d is my favorite number too!\n", after);
```

The %d format specifier looks to display an integer value. If you pass something else, like an int * in your case, it will give you strange and unexpected results.

And to make this answer more complete, to print a pointer variable, use the %p format specifier.

Answer (score -1):

The value  4223092 is the address of the "after" variable.

In C language you do not need a pointer to print a value. You only need the value of the variable. So whenever you are printing a variable just print the variable and not the pointer (address) of the variable.

So just change the following lines in your code

```
printf("%d is my favorite number too!\n", &after);
```

To

```
printf("%d is my favorite number too!\n", after);
```

Comment: `The value 4223092 is the address of the "after" variable.` you dont know that

Comment: According to my knowledge in C the "&" operator is the address operator. And it returns the address of the variable.

Comment: you knowledge is correct but incomplete, See my answer for the explanation.

Comment: Darryl Fernandes, "value 4223092 is the address" assumes `printf("%d\n", &after);` performs well.  A reasonable assumption yet still an assumption as printing a `int*` with `"%d"` is not specified behavior.  E.g. the address could be 4299190388 which has the same lower 32 bits as 4223092.  The key is that `"%d"` matches a `int` and not `int*` and that `int *` results are not defined - even if it is really turns out to be the address of `after`.  Your solution is good, but the "why" of what happened overstates.